# Hadoop HDFS Command - Rename a directory

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, command

What is the best possible way to rename a directory in HDFS?

For example, there are 2 folders A and B, each with more than 10000 files.

I want to rename B to A and A to X.

Is this possible with the mv command? In which case, what happens behind the scene (just a rename or the copy and remove)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just a rename which happens. It is very expensive to copy over all the data blocks all over. Instead it will just rename the directory and update the Namenode metadata.